# How to create a pdf viewer in WPF from scratch

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hi I'm looking forward to create a pdf viewer like the one in the **syncfusion library**, **telerik library**, I would like to learn the working of pdf viewer as I don't want to use the third party application in my application. After some searches realized that we should have to rasterise the pdf doc into image and draw the each image to a frame. Is this the correct way to start. Are there any other ways? please give suggestions

Thankyou

Comment: Is it acceptable to use a third-party rasteriser? Or are you planning to write your own?

Comment: reposting without improvement is not going to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66814128/how-to-create-a-pdf-viewer-in-wpf-from-scratch

Comment: @ASh can you please help me to improvise the question. There are no worksheets and codes to display im digging to how to start  Thankyou

Comment: @Suzz i recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for starters

Comment: i would like to do it of my own @canton7

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i will edit and repost thankyou

Comment: @Suzz If you're preparing to write your own rasterizer... Start recruiting a team, and set aside a few years. There's a reason companies charge for this

Comment: I guess the first place to start is the PDF Spec. It's around 1000 pages long and you're going to have to be intimately familiar with every single line, since you'll be implementing it all

Comment: thanks @canton7 for the information shared

Comment: @Peter I asked OP whether they wanted make their own rasterizers, and my comment is based on their response. There are many good Pdf rasterizers for .NET, and the single upvote your answer has is from me.

Comment: Ok cool thank you! I was just shouting out to you cause you said there's a reason companies pay for this. Just pointing out for everyone's sake that Pdfium is free.

Comment: @Peter Companies do charge for this -- there are plenty of paid-for PDF rasterizers out there for .NET. That's a viable business model, and a reason for that is that it's hard to write your own.

Comment: Ok I don't know why you're arguing with me. I don't disagree with anything you've said.

Comment: guys I raised the question because I have no idea about how a pdf reader works. I got some ideas after searching about it, those I included in the explanation. You are the experts who have the knowledge. I really want to do it from scratch and it is not matter how hard I have to go. Thanks @All (canton7 and Peter) for sharing the knowledge. I started learning about the PDF Spec and also I had visited the pdfium and learning how it works. Thanks for your great time.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this (now archived) project. It uses the Pdfium rasterizer which is made by Google and is open source and free. The rest of it is from scratch. It will show you everything you need to use Pdfium for what you're suggesting:

https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer

As some of the comments alluded, you're not going to realistically be able to make your own renderer from scratch. But there's no reason to. Pdfium is outstanding and interops with C#/WPF perfectly fine.